# Is it possible to load different set of data in child component, based on parameter that is changed in parent component, in Blazor Server app?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on a Blazor server app.

I am trying to pass a parameter (`int platformId`) from parent component to child component. The `platformId` defines the platform, and changing it should result in a different set of data rendered in child component.
A button is used to toggle between 2 different platformIds.

I pass the platformId successfully to child component as it's changed, but so far I couldn’t find the way to populate `listOfGrades` with data from changed platform.
It seems that once the PlatformId is set as here `<ChildComponent @ref="childComponent1" PlatformId="platformId"  />` it just cannot be changed.

Parent component:

```
@code{
    int platformId = 1;
    bool defaultSelected = false;

    public void ToggleId()
    {
        defaultSelected = !defaultSelected;
        SetPlatformId();
    }

    public void SetPlatformId()
    {
        if (defaultSelected)
            platformId = 1;
        else
            platformId = 2;
    }
}
```

Child component:

```
@code{
    public List<GradeModel> listOfGrades;

    [Parameter]
    public int PlatformId { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        listOfGrades = await gradesService.GetAllGradesAsync(platformId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can, but you're looking at the wrong event. `OnInitializedAsync` is called exactly once (or twice with server prerendering) when the component is first created. You're looking for [`OnParametersSetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.onparameterssetasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0). They're described in [ASP.NET Core Razor component lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0#after-parameters-are-set-onparameterssetasync):

> OnInitialized and OnInitializedAsync are invoked when the component is initialized after having received its initial parameters in SetParametersAsync.

On the other hand:

> OnParametersSet or OnParametersSetAsync are called:
>
> - After the component is initialized in OnInitialized or OnInitializedAsync.
> - When the parent component rerenders and supplies:
>
>   - Known primitive immutable types when at least one parameter has changed.
>   - Complex-typed parameters. The framework can't know whether the values of a complex-typed parameter have mutated internally, so the framework always treats the parameter set as changed when one or more complex-typed parameters are present.

Just change the override to be `OnParametersSetAsync` and your current logic should work as expected.

I recommend you read the linked article on lifecycle, for me it really help to understand how the Blazor magic happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was definitely a useful tip as lifecycle methods seem to be crucial for getting things done in Blazor. Unfortunately, I couldn’t solve it with OnParametersSet either.  However, I finally found a way to make it work, by using additional method as I describe below. However, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what I wanted, by using additional method that will be called both from Oninitialized, and when button is clicked:

```
public List<GradeModel> listOfGrades;
int platformId = 0;
private int PlatformIdfromIndex { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await LoadComponent(platformId);
}

public async Task LoadComponent(int platformId)
{
    listOfGrades = await gradesService.GetAllGradesAsync(platformId);
}

async Task OnPlatformButtonChange(object value)
{
    PlatformId = (int)value;
    await LoadComponent(PlatformId);
}
```